# Android problems - Background service doesn't stop

Tags: android, audio

Hello guys, I'm an absolute beginner in Android development.
I'm just now creating a simple android application and I use a "BackgroundService" for the background music.
I manage to play music; my problem is that when I close my app or press the home button, the music doesn't stop.
Can you guys help me?
Here's my code:

```
MediaPlayer player;
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample);
    player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    player.setVolume(100,100);

}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    player.start();
    return 1;
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TO DO
}
public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TO DO Auto-generated method
    return null;
}

public void onStop() {

}
public void onPause() {

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {

}
```

}

Comment: that's what a service is all about! if you want your music to stop when you leave the app, you should use an activity, not a service... or stop the service in the onStop/onPause method of your activity

Comment: use service so that every time i change activity it will continue playing i also tried using activity but when i use stop or pause method every time i change activity the music stoped

Answer (score 1):

on the onPause method, add also

```
player.stop();
player.release();
```

hope this helps

Comment: it doest work sir but thank u for answering my question

Answer (score 0):

You should really understand the concepts of a **Service**. **Service** is used for managing heavy tasks that runs in the background and don't require a UI. In simpler terms, Service is used to do heavy task in the background even if the activity is no longer visible.

**Service** will remain alive even if your activity is destroyed. You have to stop the Service manually. In the `onPause()` of your activity, try to stop the Service.

```
stopService(this, serviceClassName.class)
```

and in the `onPause()` of the Service you should stop and release the player

```
player.stop();
player.release();
```

See this link to learn more about **Service** and its **life cycle**. [developers.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: sorry for my question im so noob in this field can i ask where should i put stopService(this, serviceClassName.class)

Comment: Override the `onPause()` method of your activity. If using Eclipse then go to `Source > Override/Implement methods > onPause()` inside this you stop Service. Similarly in Service's `onPause()` you stop and release player.

Comment: I put @Override public void onPause() {
  stopService(this, MusicService.class);
 } on my first activity but stopService gives me an error

Comment: How are you starting the service?

Comment: Intent svc=new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
  startService(svc); here sir how i start service

Comment: @user3162784 My bad, the Service should be stopped using the following code `stopService(new Intent (this, MusicService.class));`